# Compute coefficients of a saturated model by hand

Tags: r, regression, matrix-multiplication, poisson

I want compute a null model,saturated model and a proposed model for a poisson regression by hand. For that i designed a loglikelihood function and optimize it with the optim function. It worked well for the null and the proposed model. For the computation of the  coefficients of the saturatetd model i get an error : "Error in beta %*% t(x) : non-conformable arguments". I know what the error means (dimensions of the matrices doesn't fit) but i dont know how to fix it, maybe you can help.

```
data <- as.data.frame(warpbreaks)

# Function for loglikelihood

LogLike <- function(y,x, par) {
  beta <- par
  # the deterministic part of the model:
  lambda <- exp(beta%*%t(x))
  # and here comes the negative log-likelihood of the whole dataset, given  the
  # model:
  LL <- -sum(dpois(y, lambda, log = TRUE))
  return(LL)
} 
formula <- breaks~wool+tension

form <- formula(formula)

#  dataFrame 
model <- model.frame(formula, data = data)

#  Designmatrix for proposed modell
x <- model.matrix(formula,data = data)

# Response Variable 
y <- model.response(model)

# modelMatrix for null Modell 
x1 <- as.matrix(x[,1])

# Computation Koef nullmodell
par1 <- rep(0,1)
koef <- round(optim(par=par1,fn=LogLike,x=x1,y=y)$par,4)
koef

# Computation koef proposed Modell
par2 <- rep(0,ncol(x))
koef2 <- round(optim(par=par2,fn=LogLike,x=x,y=y)$par,4)
koef2

# Computation koef saturated Modell
par3<- rep(0,length(y))
koef3 <- round(optim(par=par3,fn=LogLike,x=x,y=y)$par,4)
koef3
```

Answer (score 0):

A saturated model is a model that have a many parameters as data points. You need to build such a `x` matrix and everything should work. So far, `x` is a 54x4 matrix while it should be a 54x54.

--- Advice (FWIW)

Avoid using functions' names as variables (`beta` and `par` in your case).

Hope this helps.

Comment: you mean you set beta1 <- par  and it worked?? Because i tried this and it stil  doesnt work ....

Comment: R can distinguish variables from functions. You can do `c <- 1; c + 1` without any problems, although there is a function `c`.

Comment: That's absolutely correct! My point was that it is better to avoid to use a function name as a variable name (especially with generic functions).

Comment: I edited my answer so it is not misleading, thanks @Roland.

Comment: why i have to use x1 instead of x ??I know that a saturated model is a modell where i have as many coefficients as many observations i have in y. Thus is par3 coded like above.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now... so you should use `t(x)` instead of `x`! Let me know if this is it otherwise I give up and edit my answer saying I was wrong.

Comment: now the computation works but i get a 209867.4 loglikelihood. Thus i get the wrong null deviance and residual deviance compared to the glm function  so i think that your answer is wrong.,..

Comment: But shouldn't your x matrix for the saturated model be a 54x54 matrix? I guess you need to generate one on your own.